# What is the state of a variable if it is going to be used and overwritten at the same time in liveness analysis

Tags: compiler-construction

Given rules like below,
1. Read(A) {A}
2. Read(B) {A,B}
3. C = A + B {B, }
4. A = A + B {}

The elements in {} are live before the next line is read.
So, at second line, A and B are live.
At third line, I am not sure if A is gonna be live or not since it will be used in the next line while at the same time it will be overwritten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A is live at the end of line 3. You need the value of A from line 1 to compute the new value of A on line 4.